# Starting Java socket server when pressing a button and then waiting for clients

Tags: java, sockets

I am currently working on a Java LAN game. I want to be able to start a server after pressing a button. When I press a button the variables startServer and listenToClients become true. However I am getting a null pointer exception when starting to listen to clients. How can I solve this?

This is the code for the main class:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    ServerSocket ss = null;
    Socket cs = null;
    String address=Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
    InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(address);




    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                new TablaPrinc().setVisible(true);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Game.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });

    while (true) {

        if (startServer == true) {

            ss = new ServerSocket(5555,50,addr);
            System.out.println("Server started on "+address);
            startServer=false;  

        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TablaPrinc.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        if (listenToClients==true){
            cs = ss.accept();         
            System.out.println("\n we have a new client. "); 
            Connection con=new Connection(cs, ++i);

        }

    }


}
```

This is the connection class:

```
static class Connection extends Thread {

int identity;
Socket cs = null;
DataInputStream is = null;
DataOutputStream os = null;


    public Connection(Socket client, int i) throws IOException {
    cs = client;
    identity = i;
    is = new DataInputStream(cs.getInputStream());
    os = new DataOutputStream(cs.getOutputStream());

    start();
    }
    public void run(){

       while(true){

      /* Interaction between the server and the clients */
       }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you set to true the startServer variable first, then wait for it to become false again, meaning that the ServerSocket is initialized, and finally set listenToClients to true. Otherwise you may run into the situation that listenToClients is true when the ServerSocket is null, getting the NullPointerException you're talking about.

Could you provide us the full stack trace the exception prints?

Comment: I have a jFrame with two buttons: one for the server and one for the client. Here is what I want to do: When I press the server button the server should launch and start listening to clients. When I press the client button it should connect to the server. I am basically trying to both launch the server and connect to the server from the same place.

Comment: Without the full stack trace, or at least the exact line where the exception is being thrown, we can't do much.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I modified the code, got rid of the exception and this is what I have now:

The Server:

```
package game;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Inet4Address;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class GServer {
 static int i=0;
 static int numberOfPlayers=0;
 static ArrayList <String> players=new ArrayList <String> ();



 public GServer(int nrj) throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
    this.numberOfPlayers=nrj;
    ServerSocket ss = null;
    Socket cs = null;
    String address=Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
    InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(address);
    ss = new ServerSocket(5555,50,addr);
    MainFrame.jLabel18.setText("Server started on "+address);




    for (int j=0;i<nrj;j++) {
        cs = ss.accept();     
        System.out.println("\n New Client"); 
        Connection con=new Connection(cs, ++i);
        players.add(Connection.is.readUTF());
    }

   for (int i=0;i<players.size();i++){
       System.out.println("\n Player:"+players.get(i));
   }


 }

}


class Connection extends Thread {

int identity;
Socket cs = null;
static DataInputStream is = null;
static DataOutputStream os = null;


    public Connection(Socket client, int i) throws IOException {
    cs = client;
    identity = i;
    is = new DataInputStream(cs.getInputStream());
    os = new DataOutputStream(cs.getOutputStream());

    start();
    }
    public void run(){

       while(true){

       }


    }
}
```

This is the client:

```
package game;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;


public class GClient {       
public GClient() throws IOException{

    String address=MainFrame.jTextField18.getText();
    Socket cs = new Socket(address, 5555);
    MainFrame.jLabel20.setText("Connected to "+address);
    final DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(cs.getOutputStream());
    DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(cs.getInputStream());
    os.writeUTF(TablaPrinc.jTextField19.getText());
 }
}
```

This is the main class from the main frame:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

   try {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                new TablaPrinc().setVisible(true);
             } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger .getLogger(TablaPrinc.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });


    while(true){


        if (serverStart==true){
            int numberOfPlayers=Integer.parseInt(jTextField19.getText());
            GServer gs=new GServer(numberOfPlayers);
            serverStart=false;

     jButton2.setEnabled(false);
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(15);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TablaPrinc.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }




}
```

What I want to do is to disable jButton2 on all frames after the client listening ends. With this code, this happens only to the first frame

the clients connect to the server after pressing this button:

```
private void jButton11ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    jPanel3.setVisible(false);
    jLabel16.setVisible(false);
    jLabel17.setVisible(false);
    jLabel18.setVisible(false);
    jTextField18.setVisible(false);
    jTextField19.setVisible(false);
    jTextField20.setVisible(false);
    jButton5.setVisible(false);
    jButton6.setVisible(false);
    jButton7.setVisible(true);
    jLabel20.setVisible(true);
    jLabel7.setVisible(true);
    jTextField3.setVisible(true);
       try {
           GClient gc=new GClient();
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           jLabel20.setText("Connection unsuccesfull");
           Logger.getLogger(TablaPrinc.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }



}
```

Comment: Yeah I used a completely different method. I used RMI and it's way easier.  What it really annoys me is the fact that when trying to run more than 3 client jFrames the NetBeans is extremely laggy. It gets stuck scanning for external changes.

Comment: Ok that sounds strange, you should move over to javaFX and use Eclipse ;)

Comment: It's just that I got used to NetBeans. But I don't know maybe I'll try others out.